# Does trim() method removes CRLF characters also?

Tags: java, trim

Suddenly noticed that `trim()` method removes CRLF - new line - characters also..:

```
String s = "str\r\n";
s = s.trim();

System.out.println("--");
System.out.print(s);
System.out.println("--");
```

Is it intended to do so?

Comment: What does the API method say? Is there something about the API description you don't understand?

Comment: Of course it doesn't specifically list each "whitespace" character, but what does the description say that you don't understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, see the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()):

> Otherwise, let k be the index of the first character in the string
>   whose code is greater than '\u0020', and let m be the index of the
>   last character in the string whose code is greater than '\u0020'. A
>   new String object is created, representing the substring of this
>   string that begins with the character at index k and ends with the
>   character at index m-that is, the result of this.substring(k, m+1).

`CR+LF: CR (U+000D) followed by LF (U+000A)` less than `U+0020`

Comment: Why are you reading the API for the OP? He was asked to clarify what he doesn't understand about the API description. My comment was intended to force him to do the reading of the API, not you.